# Transparent background from ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-design-library

I have an `ImageView` inside a Vertical `ScrollView` now what i want to do is as long as the user scroll the Image i want the cover portions of the images to be the background in the `LinearLayout`.

> Here is my Prototype

[image]
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please add relevant code

Comment: @maRShmallow I am still finding a solution, what i have done so far is not working and what i expected.

Comment: as i understand you can use that image as a background_image in scrollview

Comment: @roshanposakya: My ScrollView has one child and that is the ImageView

Comment: <ScrollView
  background_image="@drawable/image"
>
<ImageView

/>

</ScrollView>